# Field calculator not working with ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, enterprise-geodatabase, attribute-table

I am working directly with ArcSDE and I want to add a field in the attribute table. I am able to add the field but it does not allow me to use the field calculator.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? Where is the sde sitting? Are there any other users accessing the sde (are there/ have you checked for locks?) when you say it does not allow, is the option greyed out or does it run with no result? Have you tried starting an edit session then run the field calculator?

Comment: Initially, when I was trying to add a field, it showed me locks, then through ArcGIS manager, I stopped it and was able to add the field. Now I am trying to populate the new field with the old one through field calculator but it shows grey. I am not able to click on it including statistics and calculate geometry. I have not run edit on this table.

Comment: Thank you Keagan Allan. I was missing the editing part and was trying to calculate without it. Now I am able to what I was trying.Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Cool added the answer. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

After adding the field. Start an edit session. This will allow the field calculator to work as you need.